# Horizontal layout with fullscreen scrollbar

Tags: windows-8

How can I create horizontal layout with fullscreen scrollbar? Like "Store" app in Windows 8. I use WinJS

Answer (score 0):

Try this, flexbox:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx

There is a property called ‘flex-direction’which allows you to change a row to a column, i.e. the elements would be aligned vertically. It is also possible to reverse the direction, i.e. the last element in the container would appear first in the list. This property can take the values – ‘row’, ‘row-reverse’, ‘column’ and ‘column-reverse’.